# Can my weapons have more than 3 upgrades?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

The weapon info screen shows 3 slots. They seem to be for the unique upgrades of each gun. Am I limited to only 3 upgrade installations per gun or can I add for example silencer, AP, laser as well as damage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this in-game image of the 10 mm pistol (taken from [Wikia](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Pistol_%28DX3%29)):

[image: Deus EX HR screenshot of pistol weapon information]

The three icons next to the weapon image *always* represent (in order) the Laser Sight, Silencer and a Specialist upgrade. If a weapon cannot take any of these specific upgrades they will be crossed out and they would be highlighted green if fitted. We can see in this example that the pistol can take all three, but has none yet fitted.

Below these are the weapon's four statistics. The bright orange elements here show the weapon's base performance, then there sometimes dark green bits following these. The number of dark green bits in each line is how many weapon mods of that type the weapon *can* take, and these become green when fitted. If there are no dark green bits the weapon cannot take any upgrades of that type.

Continuing on from the same example, let's look closer at this pistol's damage:

[image: Deus Ex HR Pistol damage output, highlighted]

Base damage is three units, one damage upgrade has been fitted, and the weapon will take another three (for a total of four damage upgrades).

What this means in this example, the 10mm Pistol, can take **all** of:

- Laser Sight
- Silencer
- Special Upgrade (AP Bullets)
- 4 × Rate of Fire Upgrade
- 4 × Reload Speed Upgrade
- 4 × Damage Upgrade
- 4 × Ammo Capacity Upgrade

For a maximum total of 19 different upgrades of varying types.

Comment: +1; that's a great answer. A few additional points for completeness: the three pictures to the left of the weapon picture are always laser sight, silencer, and the special weapon mod. About 1/2 the guns take the laser sight, most of those also take the silencer, and almost every gun has a special weapon mod, but each special weapon mod fits on only one or two guns.

Comment: Side note: **Gray** upgrade boxes are for RoF/Reload/Damage/Ammo, while **Orange** upgrade boxes are always the weapon-specific special upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not limited to three upgrades per gun. The three upgrade slots you see, are actually for attachments and unique upgrades, like silencer, laser sight, armor piercing, scope,  etc.

The damage output, reload speed, ammo capacity and rate of fire upgrades are different from the attachments and unique upgrades. While examining a weapon, you can see how many times to can upgrade an attribute by looking at the green bars next to the specific attribute.